# Java Error When Starting Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, fedora

Every time I start Eclipse on my laptop running Fedora 20, a new log file is created in the same folder where Eclipse was started with a name like abrt_checker_xxxx.log where xxxx is a different 4-digit number. Inside the log file there is always the same error:

```
Uncaught java.lang.ClassNotFoundException exception in thread "main" in a method java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass() with signature (Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class;
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .home.raffy.eclipse..plugins.org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) [jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc20.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar!/java/net/URLClassLoader$1.class]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) [jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc20.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar!/java/net/URLClassLoader$1.class]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc20.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar!/java/security/AccessController.class]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) [jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc20.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar!/java/net/URLClassLoader.class]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) [jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc20.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar!/java/lang/ClassLoader.class]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) [jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc20.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar!/sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader.class]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) [jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc20.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar!/java/lang/ClassLoader.class]
```

This happens when running Eclipse on both OpenJDK 7 and Oracle JDK 7. It did not happen when I had Fedora 19 with the same exact set up.

Comment: Can you run `java -version`?

Comment: Yes. It gives me the Open JDK version.

Comment: And "javac"; it looks like you're pointing at a JRE for JAVA_HOME... also, check you have the "64-bit" version of eclipse.

Comment: javac also runs fine from the terminal (Eclipse only uses the JRE anyway). I am running the 64-bit version of Eclipse. Have you ever run Eclipse on Fedora 20? I did a fresh install of everything on a different laptop and got the same exact results. It is definitely a bug somewhere and not my set up. I am just looking for a workaround (aside from writing a script that deletes the log files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to eliminate the symptoms only (the log file being created after every Eclipse start) by removing a package called abrt-java-connector from Fedora.

```
sudo yum remove abrt-java-connector
```

Like I said, this only removes the symptoms. The underlying problem is either with Fedora 20 or Eclipse and hopefully can be resolved in future versions.

The problem is not related to my set up because I was able to recreate the same problem by doing a fresh install of Fedora 20 and a fresh install of Eclipse on a completely separate laptop.

Comment: That is just the bug report tool, I have the same problem with anything eclipse based, Android Dev, Apache Directory, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your question, but I have always seemed to have had issues using OpenJDK in linux for eclipse and netbeans. I never could really pinpoint the issue because there were always different issues, and the issues did not always persist. I ended up finding a repository to get and  use the standard Java Development kit.
Which for the most part played much nicer.

Comment: The same thing happens when running Eclipse on the Oracle JDK.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read the **Known Issues** section of the **readme_eclipse.html** file which is located in **eclipse/readme** folder. It surely suggests which jdk version is required for your current eclipse installation and you may check if it matches. I strongly believe that your eclipse has mismatches with JDK like 64-bit version of jdk and 32 bit eclipse, or vice versa.

**ADD path of jre and bin**:
Fix JAVA_HOME **as well as PATH** variables ?

Comment: No, there is no mismatch. Both the JDK and Eclipse are 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Google Talk installed? If so, try uninstalling it and try again. It's a webkit issue on Fedora 20.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=334466

Comment: Yes, I knew about this. Google Talk is not installed in my system

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with gtk styles, probably you are using KDE and the gtk theme is oxygen-gtk.

Try setting the themes to defaults. It worked for me.

```
rm .gtkrc-2.0*
```

Sources:

http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=295967

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1363455#p1363455

http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=114903